# Excel: Completed tasks in Column B with date. Need percent of completed tasks, regardless of date

Tags: excel

I have a list of 42 tasks. I represent that those tasks are complete with a date (date completed). I want to calculate the percentage of tasks completed in row 45, but the percetage of tasks complete keep getting mixed up witht he dates. The date is just when the task was completed, and I want to know the percent of the tasks completed.

I haven't actually been able to figure out the code because the date is read. The date is irrelevant to the percentage of tasks completed, but it is needed for me to know WHEN it was done for annual training.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function COUNTA() to count the number of cells with values : put COUNTA(B1:B43), if the task with not dates have an empty cell. then to get the % you can do COUNTA(...)/42. hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use COUNTA(task column)/COUNTA(dates column) and also change the formatting of this cell into a number. It should work.
Formula - =COUNTA(B2:B11)/COUNTA(A2:A11)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ygc0.png)